# ImageMagick installation MediaTemple GridServer

Tags: php, imagemagick, mediatemple

I've activated the ImageMagick extension as per the [KnowledgeBase article](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1778/Is+ImageMagick+installed+on+the+%28gs%29+Grid-Service?#gs)

Basically, adding this line to `php.ini`:

```
open_basedir = /nfs:/tmp:/usr/local:/etc/apache2/gs-bin:/usr/bin/convert
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.
This script outputs the version number just fine:

```
$IM_version=shell_exec("/usr/bin/convert -version");
echo $IM_version;
```

However, when I try to use the `Imagick` class I get an error.

```
try
{
        /*** a new imagick object ***/
        $im = new Imagick();

        /*** Create a red rectangle  ***/
        $im->newImage( 200, 100, "red", "png" );

        /*** write image to disk ***/
        $im->writeImage( '/tmp/rectangle.png' );

        echo 'Image Created';
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/html/mt.php on line 8
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what the next step for troubleshooting is?

I've contacted MediaTemple support and they just said *"sorry but because the script outputs the version number it proves it's installed"*

Comment: That KB article enables you to call the ImageMagick cli tools from PHP scripts, but it does not install the Imagick PEAR class (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). I'm not seeing a simple way to use Imagick() on the (gs). It may need to be compiled from source and the extension stored locally in your path. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, I got this working but it was a bit tricky. Here goes...

First, you'll want to install ImageMagick from source. This step may be optional if you already have access to 'MagickWand-config', but it wasn't in my path. Here were the steps I followed to install it into an alternate directory on the (gs):

Note: As of this post, the latest release was 6.8.9.3.

```
$ wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.8.9-3.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz ImageMagick-6.8.9-3.tar.gz
$ cd ImageMagick-6.8.9-3
$ mkdir /home/#####/etc/imagemagick
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/#####/etc/imagemagick
$ make
$ make install
```

The Imagick PHP class is a PECL extension so we will install it using the provided [KB](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1682/Installing+PECL+extensions#gs) from Media Temple with one change. Here are the steps:

```
$ export SITEID=`pwd | awk -F\/ '{ print $3 }'`
$ export PHPPATH=`php-stable -i | grep "Configure Command" | perl -pe "s/.*'.\/configure'\s*?'--prefix\=(.*?)'.*/\1/"`
$ mkdir /home/$SITEID/data/lib
$ mkdir /home/$SITEID/data/lib/php/
$ wget http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick && tar zxvf imagick && cd imagick-* && $PHPPATH/bin/phpize
```

This is where our script deviates from the instructions. We need to specify the path to our ImageMagick install to use 'MagickWand-config'. If this isn't specified, you'll see the following error:

> checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program...
>   configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to
>   MagickWand-config or Wand-config program.

If you've used an alternate location for the source install of ImageMagick, replace the path for '--with-imagick' with that path.

```
$ ./configure --with-php-config=$PHPPATH/bin/php-config --with-imagick=/home/#####/etc/imagemagick
```

Resuming the normal instructions:

```
$ make && cp modules/*.so /home/$SITEID/data/lib/php
```

Update your php.ini file, which should be located at /home/#####/etc/php.ini and add these 2 lines:

> extension_dir=/home/#####/data/lib/php/
>
> extension = imagick.so

Once complete, here is the script I ran:

```
<?php

$IM_version=shell_exec("/usr/bin/convert -version");
echo $IM_version;

if (!extension_loaded('imagick'))
{
    echo "imagick not installed\n";
}
else
{
    echo "imagick installed\n";
}


try
{
        /*** a new imagick object ***/
        $im = new Imagick();

        /*** Create a red rectangle  ***/
        $im->newImage( 200, 100, "red", "png" );

        /*** write image to disk ***/
        $im->writeImage( '/tmp/rectangle.png' );

        echo 'Image Created';
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Output:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2012-05-03 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP 

imagick installed
Image Created
```

Comment: I followed these instructions with the current version, ImageMagick-6.9.1-0.tar.gz , and it works perfectly. YOU GUYS ARE THE BEST.

Comment: These instructions worked perfectly! With one little note:

If your PHP version is not stable but latest, you have to replace the line that says php-stable with this one:

$ export PHPPATH=`php-latest -i | grep "Configure Command" | perl -pe "s/.*'.\/configure'\s*?'--prefix\=(.*?)'.*/\1/"`

Comment: This is great. I made it through the above okay, but still seem to be having some issues. When I grab the IM version, it comes back with the one MT GS has installed by default (6.7.7-10) rather than the one I installed (7.x). Any ideas as to why his would be? Now when I try image transforms they're just hanging :/

Comment: @philzelnar Did you update your php.ini? Are you doing this via php or cli?

Comment: These instructions still work beautifully! Thank you Chris & Rich.

ImageMagick is now at version 7. If you still want to use version 6, you may need to adjust the download URL to `legacy.imagemagick.org`. For example:
`$ wget http://legacy.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.9.11-10.tar.gz`

Comment: @Jim Glad to hear!